# cannot open or write to the file It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, database, web

Cannot save my excel file in a folder that I create in my project... I think I forgot something while doing the especification of the path... Maybe I have to do something after? 
I Already put the users with permissions and things like that, I THINK that the file isnt open I just have 1 user and nothing is open..
here's the code guys:

```
protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);


        string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);

        string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
        String strConnection = @"Data Source=PEDRO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=costumizado;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1234";
        string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filepath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HRD=YES;IMEX=1;\"";

        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [Name],[city],[age] from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);


            excelConnection.Open();




            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select [Name],[city],[age] from [Sheet1$]", strConnection);

            OleDbDataReader dReader;
            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);

            sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Test";
            sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
            excelConnection.Close();


    }
```

Comment: Verify if there is another process holding your file open. Check this thread for options on how to do that: https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows

Comment: @camba1 Thanks For the answer but Nothing open that seems like excel...